# SQL Server Trigger. Need Help

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table with these columns:

- debt
- paid
- remained

Whenever the `paid` column is updated I need to recalculate the `remained` using the following calculation `debt` minus `paid`

Could someone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) instead.

This [article](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLComputedColumns.aspx) has the syntax for creating from scratch or adding to an existing schema, along the lines of

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD remainder AS debt - paid
```

Answer (score 4):

Given table

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    MyTablePK int,
    debt numeric(10,2),
    paid numeric(10,2),
    remainder numeric(10,2)
)
```

The following trigger will recalculate field Remainder

```
CREATE TRIGGER tMyTable ON [MyTable] FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
              SET NOCOUNT ON
        UPDATE mt
            Set mt.Remainder = mt.Debt - mt.Paid
            FROM [MyTable] mt INNER JOIN Inserted i
            on mt.MyTablePK = i.MyTablePK
    END
```

You could also define Remainder as a [Computed persisted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) column, which would have a similar effect without the side effects of triggers

Comment: Thanks for answering the question AND ALSO suggesting another way.  In my case, the computation is geospatial and thus not allowed as a persisted column. (Computed column xxx in table zzz cannot be persisted because the column type, 'geography', is a non-byte-ordered CLR type.)  I could create the computed column without the PERSISTED keyword, but the problem I am trying to solve is avoiding the expensive geospatial calculation at runtime.  While the persisted computed column will work for the OP, your trigger solution is what I will need to go with.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why perform a calculation in a trigger when SQL can do it for you, and you don't have to worry about triggers being disabled, etc:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    /* Other columns */
    Debt decimal (18,4) not null,
    Paid decimal (18,4) not null,
    Remained as Debt-Paid
)
```

This is called a computed column

Answer (score 2):

```
create trigger DebtPaid
on DebtTable
after insert, update
as if update(paid)
begin
    update DebtTable
    set remained = inserted.debt - inserted.paid
    where customerId = inserted.customerId
end
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

http://benreichelt.net/blog/2005/12/13/making-a-trigger-fire-on-column-change/

Answer (score 1):

Computed columns can be good but they are calculated on the fly and arent stored anywhere, for some big queries that perform long calculations having a physical denormalyzed value in Remained controlled by trigger can be better than computed columns.

In your trigger remember to only update rows that were updated , you access those by virtual table Inserted Deleted available in triggers.

Comment: Good point -- nonnb's suggestion re "computed persisted" may help if dynamic calcs are an issue.